# How to use a dictionary to print its partner value

Tags: python, dictionary

Not sure if the title is specific enough.

```
words = ['sense', 'The', 'makes', 'sentence', 'perfect', 'sense', 'now']
numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
dictionary = dict(zip(numbers, words))
print(dictionary)
correctorder = ['2', '4', '7', '3', '5', '6']
```

I'm simply trying to figure out how exactly I can print specific values from the dictionary using the correctorder array so that the sentence makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can just iterate over `correctorder` and get the corresponding dict value, then join the result together.

```
' '.join(dictionary[ele] for ele in correctorder)
```

This is assuming that you fix `numbers` to include `'7'` at the end.

```
>>> ' '.join(dictionary[ele] for ele in correctorder)
'The sentence now makes perfect sense'
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is this.

```
for i in correctorder: 
    print dictionary[i]," ",
```

Short and simple. As Mitch said, fix the 7 though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to avoid an explicit loop:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> print(itemgetter(*correctorder)(dictionary))
```

To concatenate this simply use `str.join`:

```
>>> ' '.join(itemgetter(*correctorder)(dictionary))
```